# Node.js - printing details about unexpected error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does anybody know how to print more details about unexpected error that occurred?
I have this piece of code:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err)
{
    console.log("Unexpected error occurred. " + err + ".");
    process.exit(1);
});
```

...and when error occurs this is printed: "Unexpected error occurred. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED."
There is no details about this error. Like what exactly failed, which connection, ip:port. How can I fetch that kind of data? And I don't want to use Domain module (in case somebody suggests).

Comment: Try `console.log("Unexpected error occurred:", err);`. Don't stringify the object!

Comment: err object doesn't have details about what exactly happened.

Comment: Why not? What code did throw the exception? It should've provided those information if it was relevant and known.

Comment: console.log("Unexpected error occurred:", err); printed this:
"Unexpected error occurred: { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }"

Comment: There should at least be a call stack somewhere. Try to log `err.stack` (afair).

Comment: Now this is printed:
Unexpected error occurred: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
...but still this does not mean anything to me. I need to know which connection or ip:port failed.

Comment: @anagarD If it is getting to the point where it is an uncaught exception, it means you are not binding an 'error' event handler somewhere. You'll need to do that, and then inside the handler, you'll still have a reference to the specific network connection that is failing to connect. By the time an uncaught exception happens, all of that data is gone.